# Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `xxx` on serializer `xxx`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hi i'm trying to access this url : http://192.168.1.5:8000/api/parents/ but I'm getting this error :

```
AttributeError at /api/parents/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `nom` on serializer `ParentSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Adresse` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Adresse' object has no attribute 'nom'.
```

It was working last week , but i don't remember what did I exactly changed

Here is my file  models.py :

```
class Adresse(models.Model):
 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 ville=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 region=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 quartier=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 codePostal=models.IntegerField()
 rue=models.CharField(max_length=50)


 def __str__(self):
     return 'Ville :{} ,Région: {},Quartier : {},Code Postal : {},Rue :  {} .'.format(self.ville,self.region,self.quartier,self.codePostal,self.rue)



class Ecole(models.Model):
 NIVEAU=(('Maternelle','Maternelle'),('Primaire','Primaire'), ('College','Collège'),('Lycee','Lycée'))
 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 niveau=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=NIVEAU,default='')
 nom=models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
 adresse=models.ForeignKey(Adresse,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')

 def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.nom)


class Etudiant(models.Model):

 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 nom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 prenom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 email=models.EmailField()
 tel=models.CharField(max_length=10)
 adresse=models.ForeignKey(Adresse,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')
 ecole=models.ForeignKey(Ecole,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')

 def __str__(self):
    return 'Nom : {} , Prénom : {}'.format(self.nom,self.prenom)


class Parent(models.Model):
 id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 nom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 prenom=models.CharField(max_length=20)
 email=models.EmailField()
 tel=models.CharField(max_length=10)
 etudiant=models.ForeignKey(Etudiant,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='')

 def __str__(self):
    return 'Nom : {} , Prénom : {}'.format(self.nom,self.prenom)
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: It seems you're trying to access Adresse.nom which can't be found cause this atrribute is in your class Etudiant. Please show us the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the error that I was committing , I wrote :

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset=Adresse.objects.all()
 serializer_class=ParentSerializer
```

Instead of :

```
class ParentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 queryset=Parent.objects.all()
 serializer_class=ParentSerializer
```